# Modal does not close after succesful Ajax call and return Ok() as ActionResult

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a File Upload Modal, that is initiated from an "Edit" page of a specific class (e.g. "/Case/Edit/2"). After successfully uploading a file (using dropzone.js), I would like the modal to close on success `success: function(){$("#myModal").modal.('hide')};` However, when I successfully upload a file, the modal remains open. My controller ends with a `return Ok();` What to do?

The relevant part of the CSHTML is as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditFiles(0)">Add File</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fileFormModel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 id="title" class="modal-title">Add Filedata</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="fileFormModelDiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Casename" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Casename" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Casename" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

var AddEditFiles = function (itemId) {
    var url = "/Upload/AddEditFiles?itemId=" + itemId;
    if (itemId > 0)
        $('#title').html("Edit Filedata");

    $("#fileFormModelDiv").load(url, function () {
        $("#fileFormModel").modal("show");

    });

    $('#fileFormModel').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

        //toevoeging voor dropzone
        $("#modalForm").dropzone({
            maxFiles: 100,
            success: function () {    // adding a "returnId" to this function from the controller -'return Ok(returnId)-'produced an error in the path
                //var url = "/Case/Edit/" + returnId; // this did not work
                $("#myModal").modal('hide'); // <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                    //window.location.href = url;
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        })            
    });
}
```

Comment: try changing $("#myModal").modal('hide'); with $("#fileFormModel").modal('hide');

Comment: That did the trick! I feel a little foolish of overlooking something so trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested by gaetanoM, I changed `#myModal` to `fileformModal`. That was all. In my naivity I was under the impression that myModal was sort of a protected name.